# increase HIT reward after publishing HIT in mechanical turk

Tags: mechanicalturk

Does anyone know a way to increase HITs reward after publishing them in mechanical turk?
I have published around 2000 hits, and it's going kinda slow. I'm thinking of bumping the HIT reward($ paid to turkers). But i'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ChangeHITTypeOfHITOperation.html):

> You can use `ChangeHITTypeOfHIT` to update any of the HITType properties of a HIT. All properties except for Reward can be updated at any time.

In short, it is not possible. You have to close the HITs and reissue.

**UPDATE (July 2014):**

AWS [reports on the MTurk developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=555158#555158) that you can now change the HITType of a HIT to one that with a different reward amount and that the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: According to this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI-legacy/ApiReference_ChangeHITTypeOfHITOperation.html, ChangeHITTypeOfHIT API has be unusable since 2019. What kind of API should we use now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one click on [TurkPrime.com](https://www.turkprime.com) (free for academic users) without using the API.

There are additional tools like [RESTART](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28653403/1208379) that enable you to bump your hit up by restarting the hit. This starts a new HIT and excludes all workers who completed the HIT before the "restart" which has effect of looking like a new HIT and only allowing new workers.

Comment: But is it possible to see already published HITs on mturk on TurkPrime?

Comment: @Seid.M I don't think so, but is is a _planned_ item on the feedback page: http://feedback.turkprime.com/forums/288074-general/suggestions/8523565-connect-with-mturk-account-information-on-prior-hi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. First, create a new *HIT type* that specifies the new reward, then update the HITs with that new HIT type.

Use the following functions:

- `create_hit_type` [[documentation]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.create_hit_type)
- `update_hit_type_of_hit`  [[documentation]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.update_hit_type_of_hit)

If you don't know what data to use to create the new HIT type, first retrieve the HIT type of one of the existing HITs (using `get_hit`), then create the new HIT type based on that, with updated reward.

- `get_hit`  [[documentation]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.get_hit)